# ¿Cómo hacer una migración de una base de datos de MySQL a php Laravel y adaptarla a un proyecto?

Tags: laravel, migracion

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos en MySQL, y necesito migrar esa base de datos a php Laravel para mi proyecto:

CREATE DATABASE computer_advance;

CREATE TABLE cart (
idv int(11) NOT NULL,
user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
idprod int(11) NOT NULL,
name text NOT NULL,
price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
quantity int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla cart_purchase

CREATE TABLE cart_purchase (
idcpr int(11) NOT NULL,
user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
idprod int(11) NOT NULL,
name text NOT NULL,
price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
quantity int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla categoria

CREATE TABLE categoria (
idcate int(11) NOT NULL,
nocate varchar(100) NOT NULL,
state char(1) NOT NULL,
fere timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

### --
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla categoria

INSERT INTO categoria (idcate, nocate, state, fere) VALUES
(2, 'Alcohol', '1', '2023-10-02 19:16:13'),
(3, 'Gel antibacterial', '1', '2023-10-02 19:17:18'),
(4, 'Hipoclorito', '1', '2023-10-02 19:17:46'),
(5, 'Kit', '1', '2023-10-02 19:17:59'),
(6, 'Jabón', '1', '2023-10-02 19:18:23'),
(7, 'Guantes caja x 100 unidades', '1', '2023-10-02 19:19:06'),
(8, 'Respirador', '1', '2023-10-02 19:19:21'),
(9, 'Tapabocas', '1', '2023-10-02 19:19:34'),
(10, 'Trajes (Antifluidos y Bioseguridad)', '1', '2023-10-02 19:20:44'),
(11, 'Gafas de protección personal', '1', '2023-10-02 19:21:36'),
(12, 'Caretas', '1', '2023-10-02 19:21:47'),
(13, 'Casco', '1', '2023-10-02 19:22:06'),
(14, 'Señalización', '1', '2023-10-02 19:22:26'),
(15, 'Punto ecológico', '1', '2023-10-02 19:22:52');

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla clientes

CREATE TABLE clientes (
idcli int(11) NOT NULL,
idusu int(11) NOT NULL,
tipd varchar(25) NOT NULL,
nudoc char(8) NOT NULL,
nocl varchar(35) NOT NULL,
apcl varchar(35) NOT NULL,
telfcl char(9) NOT NULL,
state char(1) NOT NULL,
username varchar(15) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
rol char(1) NOT NULL,
fere timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

### --
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla clientes

INSERT INTO clientes (idcli, idusu, tipd, nudoc, nocl, apcl, telfcl, state, username, password, rol, fere) VALUES
(0, 1, 'certificado_existencia_re', '11111111', 'Laboratorio óptico Siglo Visión', '', '987633456', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:49:36'),
(0, 1, 'cuentas_bancarias', '12312312', 'Ingeniería Coiba S.A.S', '', '873456789', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:48:07'),
(0, 1, 'registros_contables_libro', '12341234', 'HV televisión', '', '234566976', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:49:06'),
(0, 1, 'registro_unico_de_propone', '12345678', 'Edificio el Pinar 102', '', '345679876', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:45:12'),
(0, 1, 'registros_contables_libro', '1234569', 'Ibáñez y Construcciones', '', '876543234', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:46:45'),
(0, 1, 'camara_de_comercio', '23487654', 'industrias metálicas DUGAR', '', '556566565', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:48:43'),
(0, 1, 'certificado_existencia_re', '34567898', 'Droguería Cauca', '', '597654334', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:44:14'),
(0, 1, 'registro_mercantil', '43981759', 'Conjunto residencial El Cedro', '', '9359179', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:42:37'),
(0, 1, 'licencias_permisos_especi', '52367423', 'Droguería Gámeza', '', '456789987', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:44:41'),
(0, 1, 'cedula_juridica', '63276387', 'Asesores de seguros Germán Prieto y', '', '236545438', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:40:43'),
(0, 1, 'rut', '67326588', 'Colegio de árbitros ODAF', '', '345678976', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:41:44'),
(0, 1, 'dni', '76543246', 'Compu Center S.A.S', '', '345670987', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:42:13'),
(0, 1, 'cedula_juridica', '87654321', 'Global Asista', '', '78362237', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:45:45'),
(0, 1, 'camara_de_comercio', '87947893', 'Cooperativa Chiliservimos', '', '530976974', '1', '', '', '', '2023-10-02 20:43:13');

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla marca

CREATE TABLE marca (
idmar int(11) NOT NULL,
nomarc text NOT NULL,
state char(1) NOT NULL,
fere timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

### --
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla marca

INSERT INTO marca (idmar, nomarc, state, fere) VALUES
(2, 'JGB', '1', '2023-10-02 19:26:39'),
(3, 'MK', '1', '2023-10-02 19:26:54'),
(4, 'Cloralex', '1', '2023-10-02 19:34:44'),
(5, 'PQP', '1', '2023-10-02 19:41:55'),
(6, 'Protexion', '1', '2023-10-02 19:44:57'),
(7, '3M', '1', '2023-10-02 19:49:19'),
(8, 'Royal', '1', '2023-10-02 20:10:54'),
(9, 'Quios', '1', '2023-10-02 20:13:38'),
(10, 'Coraza', '1', '2023-10-02 20:15:44'),
(11, 'Workseg', '1', '2023-10-02 20:18:26'),
(12, 'Mundo industrial', '1', '2023-10-02 20:21:14'),
(13, 'Prilsol', '1', '2023-10-02 20:23:48'),
(14, 'Ecoreciclaje', '1', '2023-10-02 20:27:59');

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla orders

CREATE TABLE orders (
idord int(11) NOT NULL,
clien_numdoc char(8) NOT NULL,
nomcl text NOT NULL,
method varchar(50) NOT NULL,
total_products text NOT NULL,
total_price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
placed_on varchar(15) NOT NULL,
payment_status varchar(20) NOT NULL,
tipc varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

### --
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla orders

INSERT INTO orders (idord, clien_numdoc, nomcl, method, total_products, total_price, placed_on, payment_status, tipc) VALUES
(11, '12345678', 'Laboratorio óptico Siglo Visión', 'Tarjeta', ', Antiséptico 250ML ( 10 ), Casco certificado armadura, tipo 1 + 3 repuestos de visor en pet, calibre 18 individual ( 5 )', '277000.00', '02-Oct-2023', 'Aceptado', 'Boleta'),
(14, '11111111', 'Laboratorio óptico Siglo Visión', 'Contado', ', Punto ecológico ( 1 ), Señalización 30 CM x 15 CM ( 1 )', '206000.00', '02-Oct-2023', 'Aceptado', 'Boleta'),
(15, '12345678', 'Edificio el Pinar 102', 'Tarjeta', ', Señalización 30 CM x 15 CM ( 6 ), Traje de bioseguridad desechable ( 4 ), Tapabocas normal tela antifluido & antibacterial ( 8 ), N95 con filtro ( 1 ), Jabón antibacterial 250 ML ( 5 )', '373500.00', '02-Oct-2023', 'Aceptado', 'Boleta'),
(16, '67326588', 'Colegio de árbitros ODAF', 'Contado', ', Antiséptico 250ML ( 1 ), N95 con filtro ( 5 ), Antibacterial 220 ML ( 7 ), Guantes de nitrilo ( 10 ), Kit alcohol 750 ML + gel antibacterial 500ML ( 1 ), Jabón antibacterial 250 ML ( 4 ), Hipoclorito X 1000 ML ( 2 ), Gafas de protección personal ( 10 )', '778700.00', '02-Oct-2023', 'Aceptado', 'Boleta'),
(17, '67326588', 'Colegio de árbitros ODAF', 'Contado', ', Antibacterial 220 ML ( 5 ), Jabón antibacterial 250 ML ( 1 ), Punto ecológico ( 2 ), Guantes de nitrilo ( 1 )', '489000.00', '02-Oct-2023', 'Aceptado', 'Boleta');

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla orders_purchase

CREATE TABLE orders_purchase (
idordpur int(11) NOT NULL,
user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
idprov int(11) NOT NULL,
method varchar(50) NOT NULL,
total_products text NOT NULL,
total_price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
placed_on varchar(15) NOT NULL,
payment_status varchar(20) NOT NULL,
tipc varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

### --
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla orders_purchase

INSERT INTO orders_purchase (idordpur, user_id, idprov, method, total_products, total_price, placed_on, payment_status, tipc) VALUES
(4, 1, 6, 'Contado', ', Gafas de protección personal ( 10 ), Antibacterial 220 ML ( 20 )', '270000.00', '02-Oct-2023', 'Aceptado', 'Boleta'),
(5, 1, 9, 'Tarjeta', ', N95 con filtro ( 20 ), Guantes de nitrilo ( 30 )', '1590000.00', '02-Oct-2023', 'Aceptado', 'Boleta'),
(6, 1, 8, 'Tarjeta', ', Jabón antibacterial 250 ML ( 10 ), Antiséptico 250ML ( 40 ), Kit alcohol 750 ML + gel antibacterial 500ML ( 30 ), Hipoclorito X 1000 ML ( 20 )', '1493000.00', '02-Oct-2023', 'Aceptado', 'Boleta');

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla productos

CREATE TABLE productos (
idprod int(11) NOT NULL,
codpro char(14) NOT NULL,
nomprd text NOT NULL,
desprd text NOT NULL,
foto varchar(255) NOT NULL,
precio decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
stock char(3) NOT NULL,
idmar int(11) NOT NULL,
idcate int(11) NOT NULL,
modelo text NOT NULL,
peso text NOT NULL,
state char(1) NOT NULL,
fere timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

### --
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla productos

INSERT INTO productos (idprod, codpro, nomprd, desprd, foto, precio, stock, idmar, idcate, modelo, peso, state, fere) VALUES
(5, '1', 'Antiséptico 250ML', 'Un antiséptico en formato líquido de 250 ml para desinfección y limpieza de superficies y manos.', '719904.png', '5200.00', '50', 2, 2, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 19:30:21'),
(6, '5', 'Antibacterial 220 ML', 'Gel antibacterial en un envase de 220 ml, ideal para la higiene de manos y prevención de enfermedades.', '480366.png', '7500.00', '30', 3, 3, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 19:33:35'),
(7, '9', 'Hipoclorito X 1000 ML', 'Hipoclorito X en envase de 1000 ML, una solución confiable y efectiva para la desinfección y limpieza de superficies.', '815453.png', '20000.00', '50', 4, 4, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 19:37:21'),
(8, '6', 'Kit alcohol 750 ML + gel antibacterial 500ML', 'Un kit indispensable: 750 ML de alcohol líquido y 500 ML de gel antibacterial, ideal para mantener una higiene óptima en todo momento.', '511606.png', '28000.00', '40', 2, 5, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 19:40:19'),
(9, '8', 'Jabón antibacterial 250 ML', 'Un jabón antibacterial de 250 ML que proporciona una limpieza profunda y protección contra gérmenes y bacterias.', '71510.png', '4500.00', '10', 5, 6, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 20:36:57'),
(10, '11', 'Guantes de nitrilo', '\r\nGuantes de nitrilo: una barrera resistente y cómoda para proteger las manos en diversas aplicaciones, desde limpieza hasta cuidado de la salud.', '97289.png', '47000.00', '60', 6, 7, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 19:46:08'),
(11, '14', 'N95 con filtro', 'Mascarilla N95 con filtro, una defensa eficaz contra partículas y contaminantes del aire.', '753589.png', '9000.00', '10', 7, 8, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 19:51:02'),
(12, '19', 'Tapabocas normal tela antifluido & antibacterial', 'Tapabocas de tela antifluido y antibacterial, brindando comodidad y protección adicional en situaciones cotidianas.', '59240.png', '17000.00', '70', 8, 9, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 20:11:53'),
(13, '23', 'Traje de bioseguridad desechable', '\r\nTraje de bioseguridad desechable: una solución práctica y segura para la protección completa en entornos médicos y laboratorios.', '750460.png', '42500.00', '20', 9, 10, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 20:14:43'),
(14, '25', 'Gafas de protección personal', 'Gafas de protección personal, una defensa esencial para tus ojos en entornos laborales o de riesgo.', '425643.png', '12000.00', '50', 10, 11, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 20:16:55'),
(15, '29', 'Careta de protección facial visera', 'Careta de protección facial visera, un escudo confiable para proteger el rostro en situaciones de riesgo.', '860475.png', '17000.00', '15', 11, 12, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 20:19:34'),
(16, '31', 'Casco certificado armadura, tipo 1 + 3 repuestos de visor en pet, calibre 18 individual', 'Casco certificado tipo 1 con 3 repuestos de visor en pet, calibre 18 individual, una solución de protección sólida y completa.', '278754.png', '45000.00', '10', 12, 13, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 20:26:32'),
(17, '32', 'Señalización 30 CM x 15 CM', 'Señalización de 30 CM x 15 CM, una herramienta efectiva para comunicar información importante de manera clara y visible.', '814092.png', '6000.00', '35', 13, 14, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 20:25:29'),
(18, '35', 'Punto ecológico', 'Un punto ecológico es una ubicación designada para el reciclaje y la separación adecuada de residuos, promoviendo prácticas sostenibles de manejo de desechos.', '256988.png', '200000.00', '30', 14, 15, '', '', '1', '2023-10-02 20:29:08');

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla proveedores

CREATE TABLE proveedores (
idprov int(11) NOT NULL,
idusu int(11) NOT NULL,
rucprv char(11) NOT NULL,
nomprv text NOT NULL,
corrprv varchar(35) NOT NULL,
state char(1) NOT NULL,
fere timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

### --
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla proveedores

INSERT INTO proveedores (idprov, idusu, rucprv, nomprv, corrprv, state, fere) VALUES
(3, 1, '52378328753', 'Iconos señalización', 'Iconosseñalización@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:51:07'),
(4, 1, '12345678901', 'Asa editores', 'Asaeditores@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:51:38'),
(5, 1, '09876543210', 'Universal de extintores', 'Universaldeextintores@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:52:18'),
(6, 1, '34598765432', 'Soluciones integrales Elite Colombia', 'SolucionesintegralesEliteColombia@g', '1', '2023-10-02 20:52:46'),
(7, 1, '12341234123', 'Comercializadora SQ S.A.S', 'ComercializadoraSQS.A.S@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:53:22'),
(8, 1, '09876098766', 'Soluciones Industriales ELite', 'SolucionesIndustrialesELite@gmail.c', '1', '2023-10-02 20:54:19'),
(9, 1, '34546787651', 'Extiengenerias SAS', 'ExtiengeneriasSAS@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:55:37'),
(10, 1, '87654678987', 'Proveedor portuario', 'Proveedorportuario@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:56:08'),
(11, 1, '12121212121', 'Distribuciónes CAMACHO', 'DistribuciónesCAMACHO@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:56:41'),
(12, 1, '09809809809', 'INDUFEL COMPANY SAS', 'INDUFELCOMPANYSAS@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:57:29'),
(13, 1, '34567865434', 'Oxtisol sas', 'Oxtisolsas@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:57:58'),
(14, 1, '83566653645', 'Blue prints publicidad', 'Blueprintspublicidad@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:58:28'),
(16, 1, '63256457833', 'DSD publicidad industrial', 'DSDpublicidadindustrial@gmail.com', '1', '2023-10-02 20:59:14');

---

### --
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla usuarios

CREATE TABLE usuarios (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
nombre varchar(35) NOT NULL,
username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
correo varchar(35) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
rol char(1) NOT NULL,
fere timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
state char(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

### --
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla usuarios

INSERT INTO usuarios (id, nombre, username, correo, password, rol, fere, state) VALUES
(1, 'Administrador1', 'admin01', 'admin01@gmail.com', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', '1', '2023-09-30 17:50:51', '1');

### --
-- Índices para tablas volcadas

### --
-- Indices de la tabla cart

ALTER TABLE cart
ADD PRIMARY KEY (idv),
ADD KEY idprod (idprod),
ADD KEY user_id (user_id);

### --
-- Indices de la tabla cart_purchase

ALTER TABLE cart_purchase
ADD PRIMARY KEY (idcpr),
ADD KEY idprod (idprod),
ADD KEY user_id (user_id);

### --
-- Indices de la tabla categoria

ALTER TABLE categoria
ADD PRIMARY KEY (idcate);

### --
-- Indices de la tabla clientes

ALTER TABLE clientes
ADD PRIMARY KEY (nudoc),
ADD KEY idusu (idusu);

### --
-- Indices de la tabla marca

ALTER TABLE marca
ADD PRIMARY KEY (idmar);

### --
-- Indices de la tabla orders

ALTER TABLE orders
ADD PRIMARY KEY (idord),
ADD KEY clien_numdoc (clien_numdoc);

### --
-- Indices de la tabla orders_purchase

ALTER TABLE orders_purchase
ADD PRIMARY KEY (idordpur),
ADD KEY idprov (idprov);

### --
-- Indices de la tabla productos

ALTER TABLE productos
ADD PRIMARY KEY (idprod),
ADD KEY idcate (idcate),
ADD KEY idmar (idmar);

### --
-- Indices de la tabla proveedores

ALTER TABLE proveedores
ADD PRIMARY KEY (idprov),
ADD KEY idusu (idusu);

### --
-- Indices de la tabla usuarios

ALTER TABLE usuarios
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla cart

ALTER TABLE cart
MODIFY idv int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla cart_purchase

ALTER TABLE cart_purchase
MODIFY idcpr int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla categoria

ALTER TABLE categoria
MODIFY idcate int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=16;

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla marca

ALTER TABLE marca
MODIFY idmar int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla orders

ALTER TABLE orders
MODIFY idord int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=18;

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla orders_purchase

ALTER TABLE orders_purchase
MODIFY idordpur int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla productos

ALTER TABLE productos
MODIFY idprod int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=19;

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla proveedores

ALTER TABLE proveedores
MODIFY idprov int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=17;

### --
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla usuarios

ALTER TABLE usuarios
MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

### --
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas

### --
-- Filtros para la tabla cart

ALTER TABLE cart
ADD CONSTRAINT cart_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (idprod) REFERENCES productos (idprod),
ADD CONSTRAINT cart_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES usuarios (id);

### --
-- Filtros para la tabla cart_purchase

ALTER TABLE cart_purchase
ADD CONSTRAINT cart_purchase_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (idprod) REFERENCES productos (idprod),
ADD CONSTRAINT cart_purchase_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES usuarios (id);

### --
-- Filtros para la tabla clientes

ALTER TABLE clientes
ADD CONSTRAINT clientes_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (idusu) REFERENCES usuarios (id);

### --
-- Filtros para la tabla orders

ALTER TABLE orders
ADD CONSTRAINT orders_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (clien_numdoc) REFERENCES clientes (nudoc);

### --
-- Filtros para la tabla orders_purchase

ALTER TABLE orders_purchase
ADD CONSTRAINT orders_purchase_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (idprov) REFERENCES proveedores (idprov);

### --
-- Filtros para la tabla productos

ALTER TABLE productos
ADD CONSTRAINT productos_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (idcate) REFERENCES categoria (idcate),
ADD CONSTRAINT productos_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (idmar) REFERENCES marca (idmar);

### --
-- Filtros para la tabla proveedores

ALTER TABLE proveedores
ADD CONSTRAINT proveedores_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (idusu) REFERENCES usuarios (id);
COMMIT;

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendí bien tu pregunta.

Puedes crear las migraciones (con la misma estructura que tienen tus tablas en tu base MySQL actual) y los modelos, posteriormente puedes ejecutar tus insert o bien crear seeders para realizar los insert.

Comment: no se si me podrías hacer el favor de realizar este proceso, ya que con mi grupo no hemos podido comprender muy bien como se realiza una migración de una base de datos de MySQL a php Laravel, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Por ejemplo para la tabla marca puedes hacer lo siguiente, ejecuta desde la terminal que utilices:

```
php artisan make:model Marca -m
```

Esto te creara la migración y el modelo.
La migracion en la carpeta database\migrations
El modelo en la carpeta App\Models

Abres la migración y editas lo que artisan crea por default, quedaria algo asi.

```
 public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('marcas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nomarc')->unique()->indexable();
        $table->string('state');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 */
public function down(): void
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('marcas');
}
```

El id lo genera en automatico, al igual que la fecha de registo y ultima actualizacion.

Luego ejecutas tu migracion desde la terminal con el comando

```
php artisan migrate
```

Esto genera tu tabla en MySQl

Tu modelo debera quedar de la siguiente manera (El modelo en la carpeta App\Models):

```
  class Marca extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nomarc',
        'state'
    ];
 
}
```

Puedes insertar algunos datos por medio de un seeder o directamente desde mySql.